# Why doesn't vim adventures let me type numbers for my commands despite their examples show them?

Tags: vim-adventures

I was trying to practice using `gg` since it's not clear to me what it does with numbers as pre-fixes.

I saw their examples and then tried typing one myself but I get a complaint from the game.

I am trying to type `5gg` but I get I'm not allowed to type 5. I am I not far into the game to use numbers or why is the game even showing examples we can't use?

Example:

[image]

Error message:

[image]

Comment: The command should be `gg5`, not `5gg`, I think.

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas should have said I tried that already and it didn't work. I went back to the game and tried it again just to double check and it still gives me an error. So for me `gg5` and `5gg` don't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the answer is because you don't get the ability to usen `[count]` until level 9 and my screenshot is from level 7.

Comment: Yes, you get to use numbers later in the game.  As to why it shows you numbers when you can't use them yet -- I think the help screens are intended as a reference not just for the game, but also for using Vim in the wild.